# Why is it singular?

Tags: grammaire

> L'intelligence est la force, solitaire, d'extraire du chaos de sa propre vie la poignée de lumière suffisante pour éclairer un peu plus loin que soi, vers l'autre là-bas, comme **nous égaré** dans le noir

Why is it not *égarés*?

Answer (score 1):

Because "l'autre" is singular, the plural form being "Les autres".

Comment: "Égaré" is related to "l'autre" here, not to "nous". Punctuation is not very clear in this sentence. The problematic part could be rephrased as "l'autre là-bas, égaré comme nous dans le noir"

Comment: what does this sentence mean? it is so strange.

Comment: towards the other over there, who is lost in the dark like us ?

Comment: the word order is a bit strange to an english speaker then. why is it not "egare dans le noir comme nous